# I can't do a POST with EF Core

Tags: sql, post, entity-framework-core

with a new problem, it's because with Entity framework core web api i can't do a POST request. But if i write the same sentence in Sql Server it works.

Here is my POST:

```
     public IActionResult PostEstacion([FromBody]PostEstacionDTO postEstacionDTO) {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        var EntidadID = _context.Empresa.Where(x => x.EntidadID == postEstacionDTO.EntidadID).Select(x => x.EntidadID).FirstOrDefault();
        var NumeroEstacion = _context.Estacion.Where(x => x.NumeroEstacion == postEstacionDTO.NumeroEstacion).Select(x => x.NumeroEstacion).FirstOrDefault();
        var Clave = _context.Estacion.Where(x => x.Clave == postEstacionDTO.Clave).Select(x => x.Clave).FirstOrDefault();
        var TarID = _context.Estacion.Where(x => x.TarID == postEstacionDTO.TarID).Select(x => x.TarID).FirstOrDefault();
        var postEstacion = _context.LoadStoredProc("PostEmpresaEstacion")
            .WithSqlParam("p0", EntidadID)
            .WithSqlParam("p2", NumeroEstacion)
            .WithSqlParam("p3", Clave)
            .WithSqlParam("p4", TarID)
            .ExecuteStoredProc<PostEstacionDTO>();

        return Created();
    }
```

I use a class to execute SP from SQL Server, in another Post request it works, but here it's not.

For example if i debugging:

Here is my SP:

```
    [dbo].[PostEmpresaEstacion]
@p0 int,
@p2 varchar (max),
@p3 varchar (max),
@p4 int
as
begin
insert into Empresa(EntidadID) values (@p0)
SELECT P1 = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

insert into Estacion(EmpresaID, NumeroEstacion, Clave, TarID) values (SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @p2, @p3, @p4)

end
```

And here is my Postman POST Request

[image]

And finally my query from my SP:

```
    declare @p0 int,
 @p2 varchar (max),
@p3 varchar (max),
@p4 int

set @p0 = 1
set @p2 = 'ZXSQ12'
set @p3 = 'OPIIU7'
set @p4 = 1

begin
insert into Empresa(EntidadID) values (@p0)
SELECT P1 = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

insert into Estacion(EmpresaID, NumeroEstacion, Clave, TarID) values (SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @p2, @p3, @p4)

end
```

As I said, it works perfect in Sql Server.

When i debugging in Visual Studio:

- EntidadID = 1
- NumeroEstacion = null
- Clave = null
- TarID = 2

Only "NumeroEstacion" and "Clave" are null, and i don´t know why, if i declare the variables as the others.

I will appreciate your help

Comment: When debugging, is `postEstacionDTO` variable correctly populated (especially the `NumeroEstacion` and `Clave` members)?

Comment: Yes, here is one screenshot: [link]https://ibb.co/djparn

Comment: What do you mean by "yes", I see them being `null`. So the problem is unrelated to EF Core, but the `PostEstacionDTO` class or something else. Can we see that class?

Comment: Well, only two variables are null, that's my question, because i use the same sentence in all and in the other two variables i obtain the result

Comment: Sure, here is the class:
`        // Empresa
        public int EntidadID { get; set; }
        // Estacion
        public string NumeroEstacion { get; set; }
        public string Clave { get; set;  }
        public int? TarID { get; set; }`

Comment: I'm not sure if it is this, but I made a migration after having created the first one because I had only misnamed the "NumeroEstacion" and now I left it as I show it

Comment: Btw, the question was about `postEstacionDTO.Clave` value (not `var Clave` which you seem to be showing in the screenshot). I mean, let first make sure you receive correct values and then if the problem is from `_context.Estacion.Where(x => x.Clave == postEstacionDTO.Clave)...`

Comment: @IvanStoev Well, i take a photo of the postEstacionDTO, and receive values, here is the link: [link]https://ibb.co/n9E8Bn .
So maybe the problem is in the variable sentence

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you need to query the database to get the same values that you receive from the client. 

e.g. var EntidadID = _context.Empresa.Where(x => x.EntidadID == postEstacionDTO.EntidadID).Select(x => x.EntidadID).FirstOrDefault();

In this code you search in the database a row that have EntitadID = value_from_client, and after that you select that id that you use in searching.. (value_from_client) why do you need to query the database instead simply send parameters received from client to stored procedure

Comment: because I had a similar problem before, and so I was able to find a "solution" like that, :/

Comment: Well, I think that has already been solved. You helped me debugging, thank you :)

Comment: but you only add load to database

Comment: @IsaíasOrozcoToledo post your answer

Comment: Wait a moment.. lol. Every time i do this: _context... I'm comparing with what i already have in the database. Now i analyze it in that way, what happened is that this part was explained to me by a friend in that way, then the confusion remained. So, i only do this:

Comment: `var EntidadID = postEstacionDTO.EntidadID;
 var NumeroEstacion = postEstacionDTO.NumeroEstacion;
 var Clave = postEstacionDTO.Clave;
 var TarID = postEstacionDTO.TarID;
 var postEstacion = _context.LoadStoredProc("PostEmpresaEstacion")
                .WithSqlParam("p0", EntidadID)
                .WithSqlParam("p2", NumeroEstacion)
                .WithSqlParam("p3", Clave)
                .WithSqlParam("p4", TarID)
                .ExecuteStoredProc<PostEstacionDTO>();

            return Created("DefaultApi", new {controller="estacion", mensaje = "Nueva estación agregada" })`